# Solutions of Kafka project to analyze HTTP requests on web server

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api, apache-kafka-streams

*Context*:

1. A Web server that receives millions of HTTP requests every day. Of
   course, there must be a project(named handler) who is responsible for handling
   these requests and response them with some information.
2. Seen from the server side, I would like to use **Kafka** to extract some information from them and analyze it in real time(or each time interval).

*Question*:

1. how can I use these requests as the **producer** of Kafka?
2. how to build a **customer** of Kafka?(all this data need to be analyzed and then returned, but Kafka is "just" a message system)

*Some imaginations*:

A1.1 Maybe I can let the project "handler" call the jar of Kafka then, it can trigger the producer code to send message Kafka.

A1.2 Maybe I can create another project who listens to all the HTTP requests at the server, but there are other HTTP requests at the server.

I tried to think a lot of solutions, but I am not so sure about them, I would like to ask your guys **if you have already known some mature ideas or you have some ideas to implement this**?

Answer (score 0):

You can use elk . kafka as the log broker

Comment: hey, thank you for your answer first, but I think elk + Kafka will be too big , I am new to Kafka, maybe I should try some simple solution with just Kafka first, then I can try to use other technologies to do more complicated stuff